# Provider for a user profile, Flutter x Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter/firestore. I would like to create a Provider class, where I put the general information of a user. I would like this information to be taken from firestone with Stream so that it is updated in real time.

For now I'm at the point where I get a Future<Map<String,dynamic>> with the current profile information saved on Firestone. Now I would like to switch to a simple map to extract the data, but I can't convert to `Map<String,dynamic>`.

This is the provider I created for now:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyUsers extends ChangeNotifier {
  late Map<String, dynamic> user = await getFutureUser(); // error here (await), reported below

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getFutureUser() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email!)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) =>
            documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
    return data;
  }
}
```

ERROR:

> The await expression can only be used in an async function.
> Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'

I don't understand why this error is if the function is already marked as async. I made a print of documentSnapshot.data() and it actually contains the information I want but since it is not a map, but an Object?, I can't extract it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to initialize a variable with an async function, and that cannot be possibile because when the initializer starts, it needs something to assign to that variable, but the async function has not finished yet, so it gives you the error.

So, how you resolve this?
You can make your map nullable and then call the function `getFutureUser()` and make the function that assigns the result on your map.
Or you can use a simple empty map to initialize your user map, and then call the function `getFutureUser()` to popolate it.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyUsers extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, dynamic> user = {}; //initialize the map to empty
  // Map<String, dynamic>? user; // make the map nullable

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getFutureUser() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email!)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) =>
            documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
    user = data; //assign the new map to yours
  }
}
```

Note that in this way, it's not populated in realtime, but you have to call the function `getFutureUser()` every time you want to re-fetch the data from the database.
You could use a listener to check if something has changed and then add the changes to your map.
And i suggest you to make a way to check if the database has changed from the last time (since you can set the source option in your get) to limit the number of reads.
An exemple can be create a document `Version` in your database and updating it every time you make changes on the database.
And everytime you want to fetch the data, you can check if the version has changed from the last time you fetched data.